# Find a string in a column and categorize the row

Tags: python

Need help with a situation. Please let me know what would be the best solution to this.

I have a master data frame which is below.

```
df_master = pd.DataFrame({'sentence' : ['John is a boy','amie is a girl','helen is a girl','ram is a boy','sita is a girl', 'John is a boy', 'amie is a girl']})
```

From the above DF I create another DF with unique rows and write it into an excel and add two new columns to it `"Find"` and `"Category"`). Below is the DF how it will eventually look

```
df_unique = pd.DataFrame({'sentence' : ['John is a boy','amie is a girl','helen is a girl','ram is a boy','sita is a girl'],
                         'find':['boy','girl',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                          'category': ['male','female',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})
```

Now I need the `df_master` to be modified which should finally look as below.
To achieve this I will have to first read rows from `df_unique` DF one by one and search for the word in `"find"` column in the `'sentence'` column of `df_master` and then populate the `'category'` column from the `df_unique` DF to the `'category'` column in `df_master_final` DF

```
df_master_final = pd.DataFrame({'sentence' : ['John is a boy','amie is a girl','helen is a girl','ram is a boy','sita is a girl', 'John is a boy', 'amie is a girl'],
                                'category': ['male','female','female','male','female','male','female']})
```

Please note the above is a sample and I am talking of approx 5000 rows in df_master and approx 2000 rows in `df_unique` df.

How and hat would be the best  method to achieve this as I will have to look through bot the DF and iterrows is very very slow.

Comment: Can you share the iterrorws solution you have tried? are you using it on one or both dataframes?

Comment: I have used it on both of the DF. To be honest I did not implement the logic. I was doing two iterrows and just printing the count of rows and it seems it would run for ever.

Comment: Also what should be done with the NaN rows in `df_unique`, do we exclude them? Do you effectively want to do a non-equi join `ON df_unique.find in df.sentence`?

Comment: I need not pull the df_unique rows where the find is nan because the above two lines will categorize every row so I can ignore it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fully vectorized solution. It assumes only one of the search keys can / should be matched.

```py
# Preparing the result dataframe.
df_master_2 = df_master

# Preparing the lookup dataframe to contain non-empty mapping.
mapped = df_unique[np.logical_not(df_unique.find.isna())][['find', 'category']]

# Extracting the lookup values from the sentence column.
keys_re = '.*({}).*'.format('|'.join(mapped.find.values))
df_master_2['find'] = df_master_2.sentence.str.extract(keys_re)

# Joining the category.
df_master_2 = pd.merge(df_master_2, mapped, on=['find'])

# Selecting only the fields we want.
df_master_2 = df_master_2[['sentence', 'category']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Have never heard of the vectorized solution concept. So will have to understand what it is before trying to understand what is happening in the above code. I am actually new to python and just learning the concepts.

Comment: vectorized just means that we led numpy / pandas handle the loops on the c-implementation level rather than looping over rows manually ourselves. This is much faster as it avoids the python interpreter overhead. We pass "vectors" of data to functions that are implemented to handle vectors instead of passing individual values.

Comment: Thanks. Got to learn something new.